# Possible to autoLink in a TextView, but have callback called before handling?

Tags: android

I'd like to have phone numbers in text I get from a server be clickable, but I don't want the dialer to come up automatically...I want to dialog the user first before calling.  Is it possible to set a handler for those clicks so I don't have to do the pattern matching and spannable string myself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Control onclicklistener in autolink enabled textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624297/control-onclicklistener-in-autolink-enabled-textview)